# How to get Win XP to keep wireless connection after logging off?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I have a windows XP machine that I use for some legacy software. It's only connected via wireless -- no ethernet connection.

When I log off the wireless connection is closed, and re-opened when I log back in. I'd like to be able to remote desktop into the machine from my mac, but obviously I can't do that if it's not connected to the wireless network.

Is there a way I can get Win XP (SP3) to keep a constant wireless connection regardless of who is (or isn't) logged in?

Comment: What make/model wireless card do you have installed?

Comment: Intel Pro Wireless LAN 2100 3B Mini PCI Adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that **Power Save Mode** is set to **Disabled**.

[image]

(sometimes it's called CAM, constantly awake mode)

Comment: Looks like the right answer, but alas my wireless driver (I've got the latest version) doesn't have either of those options. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm curious what CAM \ PSP has to do with keeping a connection active after a Windows user logs off? CAM is part of the WiFi stack that dynamically controls the RF power of the radios, it should have nothing to do with the user's logon state.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading and installing the latest driver *and* software package from [**Intel**](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Wireless+Networking&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+WiFi+Products&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+PRO/Wireless+2100+Network+Connection).

During the installation, I believe there is an option to allow the wireless to connect before logon, called something like "[Pre-logon Connect (PLC)](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/cs-014563.htm)".

You could also try the [Intel® Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/support/detect.htm?iid=dc_spotlight_home1) to find the right driver and software or search for the driver/software on your computer manufacturer's website.

Note - I did have problems with this a while ago and had to fully uninstall the driver, the software and then restart before I was permitted to install with this option selected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own wakeup from sleep Network Repair. I tried many answers; here's what worked for me:

Open Command Prompt and type

`ipconfig /renew`

The WAN came back on demand in seconds.
If want get a new lease DHCP then first type:

`ipconfig /release`

then renew it by using the above command.